# Spring data hibernate exception: identifier of instance was altered

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have spring boot application which use spring data and hibernate to fetch and insert data to database. 
I have one-to-many table relation:

```
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = { "id" })
@Table(name = "direction")
public class Direction {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "subdivision")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode()
public class Subdivision {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "direction_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Direction direction;
}
```

I have lombok plugin for boilarplate code generation.
I also have repository

```
public interface SubdivisionRepository extends CrudRepository<Subdivision, Long> {

List<Subdivision> findAll();

List<Subdivision> findByDirection(Direction direction);

}
```

and service

```
@Service
public class SubdivisionServiceImpl implements SubdivisionService {

@Autowired
private SubdivisionRepository subdivisionRepository;

@Override
public List<Subdivision> findAll() {
    return subdivisionRepository.findAll();
}

@Override
public Subdivision findById(Long id) {
    return subdivisionRepository.findById(id).get();
}

@Override
@Transactional
public void save(Subdivision subdivision) {
    subdivisionRepository.save(subdivision);
}

@Override
public List<Subdivision> findByDirection(Direction direction) {
    return subdivisionRepository.findByDirection(direction);
}
}
```

That's all. Then I try to update subdirection by changing direction type it shows hibernate exception: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of com.entity.Direction was altered from 2 to 3]

I found the same question on stackoverflow but nothing suggested helped. 
I tried to change fetch type and cascade type but it didn't helped.

Does anyone have solution?

P.S Here the code how I update entity

```
public void updateSubdivision(Subdivision subdivision){
    Direction d = directionService.findById(subdivision.getDirection().getId());
    Subdivision s = new Subdivision();
    s.setDirection(d);
    s.setName(subdivision.getName());
    s.setId(subdivision.getId());
    subdivisionService.save(s);
}
```

It's controller method

Comment: why not trying to generate with sequence instead of identity?

Comment: _Then I try to update subdirection by changing direction type_ Please share that code

Comment: @WeareBorg, because I use postresql and if I change sequence to identity it gives me relation "hibernate_sequence" does not exist error.

Comment: Then define that sequence in ur posgresql database.. u can do that easily in pgadmin. And name that sequence here.

Comment: @Lesiak, added update method code

Comment: Why not call `subdivisionService.save(subdivision)` directly instead of getting the direction, creating a new subdivision `s` and populating the fields from `subdivision`? And on a different note, is the `updateSubdivision(Subdivision subdivision)` or its caller is having an `@Transacation` annotation?

Comment: Could you post the complete exception stack trace?

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu, I use subdivisionService.save(subdivision) directly, but it didn't work. To demonstrate code I did this boilerplate code actions. Yes saveSubdivision has Transactional annotation.
 Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of com.entity.Direction was altered from 2 to 3] is the complete stack trace. I fixed this exception by creating absolutely new Object from fields selected from database again. Code work but it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: I tried your code, and the problem is not in the snippets you presented - the updates run fine (except that your `updateSubdivision` method updates nothing)